# How to send and receive data using Pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial, serial-communication, can-bus

I want to send and receive data between two serial ports.I am using CANtact toolkits as my serial devices.I used the following code

write.py:

```
import serial
#init serial port and bound
# bound rate on two ports must be the same
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600)
print(ser.portstr)

#send data via serial port
serialcmd=("012345688902341")
ser.write(serialcmd.encode())
ser.close()
```

listen.py

```
import serial
serBarCode = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)

while True:

    #read data from serial port
    serBarCode = serBarCode.readline()

    #if there is smth do smth
    if len(serBarCode) >= 1:
        print(dataBarCode.decode("utf-8"))
```

I get the following error:

hp@HP-Notebook:~$ cd /home/hp/Desktop

hp@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$ python3 write.py

/dev/ttyACM1

hp@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$ python3 listen.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "listen.py", line 7, in

serBarCode = serBarCode.readline()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readline'

hp@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$

Answer (score 1):

```
serBarCode = serBarCode.readline()
```

You're overwriting your serial object `serBarCode` with the data you're reading from it.
So the loop runs properly the first time, but in the following iteration, your serial object has been replaced with bytes you read from it previously

Do this instead:

```
data = serBarCode.readline()
if len(data) >= 1:
    print(dataBarCode.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: The error got resolved but still I don't get the output printed

Comment: You're passing `/dev/ttyACM2` to your write.py but it's actually writing to `/dev/ttyACM1`. And your listen.py reads from `/dev/ttyACM0`. What you write to ACM1 won't be available on ACM0 unless there's some other process in the system reading from ACM1 and writing to ACM0

Comment: Does the device I am using for serial communication matter? I am using CANtact which generally sends a CAN message also should I create a socket between the two devices?

Comment: Are `listen.py` and `write.py` supposed to run on the same machine?

Comment: @annonymous It matters if there is a specific protocol required to communicate between the units.  Otherwise, it may drop your data.

Comment: If you suspect that your serial devices are sending data over the serial ports but your script isn't reading it, you can try manually sending and receiving data from the ports. Try `echo "012345688902341" > /dev/ttyACM1` and then do `cat /dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: I get the following errors when I try echo and cat bash: echo: write error: Input/output error and cat: /dev/ttyACM0: Input/output error

Comment: @suicidalteddy write.py and listen.py run on two different devices

Answer (score 0):

You write that you are using CANtact devices.

These devices do not understand `"012345688902341"`.

The device speaks a certain protocol. E.g. for sending a CAN message, the command starts with `t` followed by the CAN-ID, followed by the DLC, followed by the data and so on.

Other commands start with `F`, `K`, etc.

Your message is most likely simply ignored by the CANtact device.

You should definitely use a higher-level library like `pyvit` for using the device.

Comment: will pyvit be able to accept messages like "012345688902341"?

Comment: Yes, pyvit can be used to send data. It will handle the communication with the CANtact device and speak the serial protocol so that the device does know what to do.

Your message is larger than 8 bytes, so you will most likely want to use ISO-TP to transfer your data.

Comment: I used this data 012345688902341 for testing purpose but I actually want to send a string of data like this 7f33117cf266a525a029a59541b3e80f3f which is nothing but a hashed CAN message. I tried ISO-TP to send this message but at the receiver side, I received the message in fragments. These fragmented messages where not in the order it was sent and I couldn't reassemble it. That's the reason why I moved to serial communication. I want the message sent at the sender side to be received as such at the receiver side. Is there any method available for that?

Comment: In this case you talk to a serial device, which has nothing to do with serial communication over CAN. ISO-TP is the way to go here. Of course the receiver side also has to talk ISO-TP. Receiving fragments out of order (in a CAN network of two nodes) is only possible when they are sent out of order.

Comment: Does the CANtact accept only CAN message not any other format such as string,data,text file?

Comment: CANtact is a piece of hardware for sending and receiving data on the CAN bus. Thus it can only send and receive CAN messages. But you can of course wrap your string, data, file, etc into CAN messages and send and receive those.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Could you suggest any websites, projects, Git Repositories for reference as I am new to this domain

Comment: Just realized that this is not your only question I have answered. Pyvit does have support for ISO-TP. For general information about ISO-TP just look at Wikipedia. The protocol is described there. In general it might be a good idea to read about the OSI model and understand the different layers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189544/discussion-between-annonymous-and-m-spiller).